# Adding Outlets to UICollectionViewCell in Storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm working with a UICollectionView in Storyboards. I've set the prototype cell to my custom UICollectionViewCell.

[image: UICollectionViewCell]

I've also set the UICollectionViewController to my custom UICollectionViewController.

[image: UICollectionViewController]

But for some reason, when I try to modify the prototype cell in my Storyboard the Assistant Editor always selects my controller and not the cell. This is the same for creating a UICollectionViewController, or placing it all individually together (UIViewController + UICollectionView).

[image]

I don't have the option to change it to a cell within the automatic dropdown and selecting the cell manually I can't add outlets.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for some reason opening it with XCode 5.1.1 fixed the problem also in XCode 6.1

Comment: If Xcode doesn't behave as you need when using the assistant editor, just select "Manual" instead of "Automatic" and browse through your files and select the one you need.